# How to make variable bar widths in ggplot2 not overlap or gap

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, geom-bar

geom_bar seems to work best when it has fixed width bars - even the spaces between bars seem to be determined by width, according to the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html). When you have variable widths, however, it does not respond as I would expect, leading to overlaps or gaps between the different bars (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345943/bar-graph-in-ggplot2-with-width-as-a-variable-and-even-spacing-between-bars)).

To see what I mean, please try this very simple reproducible example:

```
x <- c("a","b","c")
w <- c(1.2, 1.3, 4) # variable widths
y <- c(9, 10, 6) # variable heights

ggplot() + 
geom_bar(aes(x = x, y = y, width = w, fill=x), 
 stat="identity", position= "stack")
```

What I really want is for the different bars to be just touching, but not overlapping, like in a histogram.

I've tried adding `position= "stack"`, `"dodge"`, and `"fill`, but none work. Does the solution lie in `geom_histogram` or am I just not using `geom_bar` correctly?

[image: geom-plot overlap]

P.s. to see the issue with gaps, try replacing `4` with `0.5` in the above code and see the outcome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems that there isn't any straightforward solution, so we should treat x-axis as continuous in terms of `w` and manually compute required positions for ticks and bar centers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354545/1320535) is useful):

```
# pos is an explicit formula for bar centers that we are interested in:
#        last + half(previous_width) + half(current_width)
pos <- 0.5 * (cumsum(w) + cumsum(c(0, w[-length(w)])))
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = pos, width = w, y = y, fill = x), stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = x, breaks = pos)
```

[image]

Comment: That solves the problem, many thanks. Perhaps a functionality for ggplot2 devs to consider adding as a position option?

Comment: @RobinLovelace, no problem. Maybe, you could try to [ask](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues) for one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did as for this https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/890 but can't see this on the ggplot issues page. Seems to have been removed - any ideas?

Comment: @RobinLovelace, seems fine to me. I believe it will be moved to "feature" in case they will think this feature should be added.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `scale_x_discrete` for something like this?

Comment: @DaNiu, as far as I know none of the parameters of `scale_x_discrete` allows do to that. There is no way to measure the x-axis when data is discrete. Feel free to share your approach with us if you are aware of one.

Comment: @RobinLovelace, I looked at adding this to ggplot2 as well but it wasn't obvious to me that it would fit into neatly e.g. as a geom. So I started with the answer above and wrote a function, then a package- see the answer I just added to this question

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't think you need `0.5 * (...)`

Answer (score 4):

You can now do this with the `mekko` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mekko/vignettes/mekko-vignette.html